# Change music with a variable in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I want to change the song with a variable but can not do that.

```
Button btnSpeaker = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSpeaker);
        btnSpeaker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MediaPlayer file = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this , R.raw.file1);
                file.start();
            }
        });
```

Comment: _"but can not do that"_ Why not? There's no clear problem description here.

Comment: I want to change this  R.raw.file1

Comment: like  R.raw.file2,  R.raw.file3 ....  R.raw.file1000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Button btnSpeaker = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSpeaker);
                btnSpeaker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        MediaPlayer mp;
                        mp=MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getIdentifier(word.toLowerCase(),"raw",getPackageName()));
                        mp.start();
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.file1);
    Button btnSpeaker = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSpeaker);
    final int[] resources={R.raw.file1,R.raw.file2};
    btnSpeaker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int resource;
            //if u meant getting resource variable from the file name
            resource=getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier("file2","raw",getPackageName());
            //or
            resource=resources[index];

            mediaPlayer.reset();
            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext().getResources().openRawResourceFd(resource).getFileDescriptor());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });
```